# difference between innerhtml and appendChild in this case

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to recognize a difference between innerHTML and appendChild.
I know that innerHTML wipes out content of current node and replaces it with new content and makes it re-parsed. However, I see that result does not meet my expectation. How does it come like this? (I'm using google chrome)

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
var a = document.createElement("h1");
var b = document.createTextNode("Hello World");
a.appendChild(b);
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = a; //result = [object HTMLHeadingElement]

var c = "<h1>HEllo WORLD</h1>";
document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = c ; //result = Hello World
});
```

Comment: What doesn't meet your expectation? and where are elements with ids `1` and `2`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the answer in your question : innerHTML replace the content "as is" in the targeted text node. So if you do not provide a String to the innerHTML function it will display the result of the "toString" apply on the object you give. In your case "a" is a [object HTMLHeadingElement].